# how to get elements from list in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Here is a LIST:

```
List = "abcd 1234 jvm something"
```

How to get the second element "1234" without looping all the list?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

no spaces between equal sign

```
$ List="abcd 1234 jvm something"
$ set -- $List
$ echo $2
1234
```

Some other ways, although not as efficient as using shell's internals

```
$ echo $List | cut -d" " -f2
1234
$  echo $List | awk '{print $2}'
1234
$ echo $List | sed 's/^.[^ \t]* //;s/ .*//'
1234
$ echo $List | tr " " "\n"|sed -n '2p'
1234
```

Comment: Thanks.would you give some comments in the code please?

Comment: I mean the second line.

Comment: @Spawn `set -- $something` splits `$something` at the `$IFS` character (by default space) and assigns the split parts to the positional variables `$1`,`$2`,...

Comment: As @BenjaminBannier says in his answer: using set this way may pollute the environment. I.e. by overwriting positional parameters. To suggest it as an answer without explaining what it does is irresponsible.

Answer (score 64):

Just to supplement ghostdog's answer: you could also put `$List`'s elements into an array and access the specific list element from there

```
List="abcd 1234 jvm something"
arr=($List)
echo ${arr[1]}
```

Note that the array indices are counted 0,1,2,... .

This has the advantage of not polluting the shell environment with too many new variables.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier, how can you select multiple elements. Is there some syntax like ${arr[1,2,3]}$ (not this, since I tried, but like this) or do I need to use a for loop.

Comment: @Kvothe, you can take a slice from the list and loop over them. E.g. `for v in "${arr[@]:1}"; do echo "$v"; done` ... (i) takes all array elements `"${arr[@]}"`, (ii) gets a slice of them, consisting of 2nd through last elements `"${arr[@]:1}"`, and (iii) loops each into `$v`.